# Custom function: allow unknown number of groups for operations

Tags: r, function, loops, ggplot2, dry

#### Within a custom function, how can I avoid repeating the same code for each group while allowing an unknown number of groups?

Here's a simpler example but assume the function has tons of operations, like calculating different statistics for each group and sticking them on each ggplot facet. Sorry, I find it difficult to make a simpler function to demonstrate this specific challenge.

```
test.function <- function(variable, group, data) {
  if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}
  if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
  if(!require(ggrepel)){install.packages("ggrepel")}
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  require(ggrepel)
  data$variable <- data[,variable]
  data$group <- factor(data[,group])

  # Compute individual group stats
  data %>%
    filter(data$group==levels(data$group)[1]) %>%
    select(variable) %>%
    unlist %>%
    shapiro.test() -> shap
  shapiro.1 <- round(shap$p.value,3)
  data %>%
    filter(data$group==levels(data$group)[2]) %>%
    select(variable) %>%
    unlist %>%
    shapiro.test() -> shap
  shapiro.2 <- round(shap$p.value,3)
  data %>%
    filter(data$group==levels(data$group)[3]) %>%
    select(variable) %>%
    unlist %>%
    shapiro.test() -> shap
  shapiro.3 <- round(shap$p.value,3)

  # Make the stats dataframe for ggplot
  dat_text <- data.frame(
    group = levels(data$group),
    text = c(shapiro.1, shapiro.2, shapiro.3))

  # Make the plot
  ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, fill=group)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_grid(group ~ .) +
    geom_text_repel(data = dat_text,
                    mapping = aes(x = Inf, 
                                  y = Inf, 
                                  label = text))
}
```

Works if there's three groups

```
test.function("mpg", "cyl", mtcars)
```

[image]

Doesn't work if there's two groups

```
test.function("mpg", "vs", mtcars)

 Error in shapiro.test(.) : sample size must be between 3 and 5000
```

Doesn't work if there's more than three groups

```
test <- mtcars %>% mutate(new = rep(1:4, 8))
test.function("mpg", "new", test)

 Error in data.frame(group = levels(data$group), text = c(shapiro.1, shapiro.2,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3
```

**What is the trick programmers usually use to accommodate any number of groups in such functions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asked in the comments to explain the thinking here, so I thought I would expand on the original answer, which shows up below the horizontal rule below.

The main question is how to do some operation on an unknown number of groups.  There are lots of different ways to do that.  In any of the ways, you need the function to be able to identify the number of groups and adapt to that number.  For example, you could do something like the code below.  There, I identify the unique groups in the data, initialize the required result and then loop over all of the groups.  I didn't use this strategy because the for loop feels a bit clunky compared to the `dplyr` code.

```
un_group <- na.omit(unique(data[[group]]))
dat_text <- data.frame(group = un_group, 
                     text = NA)
for(i in 1:length(un_group)){
  tmp <- data[which(data[[group]] == ungroup[i]), ]
  dat_text$text[i] <- as.character(round(shaprio.test(tmp[[variable]])$p.value, 3))
}
```

The other thing to keep in mind is what's going to scale well.  You mentioned that you've got lots of operations the code will ultimately do.  In what's below, I just had `summarise` print a single number.  However, you could write a little function that would produce a dataset and then `summarise` can return a number of results.  For example, consider:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  s = shapiro.test(x)
  data.frame(p = s$p.value, stat=s$statistic, 
             mean = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
             sd = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
             skew = DescTools::Skew(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
             kurtosis = DescTools::Kurt(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  
}
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(myfun(mpg))
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#     cyl     p  stat  mean    sd   skew kurtosis
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     4 0.261 0.912  26.7  4.51  0.259   -1.65 
# 2     6 0.325 0.899  19.7  1.45 -0.158   -1.91 
# 3     8 0.323 0.932  15.1  2.56 -0.363   -0.566
```

In the function above, I had the function return a data frame with several different variables.  A single call to `summarise` returns all of those results for the variable for each group.  This would certainly have been possible using a for loop or something like `sapply()`, but I like how the `dplyr` code reads a bit better.  And, depending on how many groups you have, the `dplyr` code scales a bit better than some of the base R stuff.

I really like trying to reflect the inputs (i.e., input variable names) in the outputs - so I wanted to find a way to get around making variables called `group` and `variable` in the data.  The `aes_string()` specification is one way of doing that and then building a formula using the variable names is another.  I recently just encountered the `reformulate()` function, which is a more robust way of building formulae than the combination of `paste()` and `as.formula()` I was using before.

Those were the things I was thinking about when I was answering the question.

---

```
test.function <- function(variable, group, data) {
  if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}
  if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
  if(!require(ggrepel)){install.packages("ggrepel")}
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  require(ggrepel)

  # Compute individual group stats
  
  data[[group]] <- as.factor(data[[group]])
  
  dat_text <- data %>% group_by(.data[[group]]) %>% 
    summarise(text=shapiro.test(.data[[variable]])$p.value) %>% 
    mutate(text=as.character(round(text, 3)))
  
  gform <- reformulate(".", response=group)
  # Make the plot
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=variable, fill=group)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_grid(gform) +
    geom_text_repel(data = dat_text,
                    mapping = aes(x = Inf, 
                                  y = Inf, 
                                  label = text))
}
test.function("mpg", "vs", mtcars)
```

[image]

```
test.function("mpg", "cyl", mtcars)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant... You got rid of the redundant manually defined `group` and `variable` through the use of `aes_string()`  in the `ggplot` call, as well as the use of double square brackets elsewhere. You also add `reformulate()`, which I didn't know about, to feed the `facet_grid()` call. Finally, you include the shapiro test within the `dplyr` call using `summarize`. Nice! Do you think you could explain your general strategy/mindset when you came up with this at the beginning of your answer? I think it could be helpful to learn from it! :)

Comment: Thanks.  I added an explanation at the start of the answer above.

Comment: Amazing explanations and very appreciated. That's a high-quality answer. I wish more people would see it. Edit: Not much, but I shared your answer on Twitter! https://twitter.com/RemPsyc/status/1368618801437302794?s=20

Comment: @RemPsyc Thanks for the kind words.  Glad it was helpful.