# Avoid repeated geom calls in ggplot function with facet grid and unknown number of groups?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, visualization, density-plot

I am attempting to write a density function that will apply a normal curve as a reference for each facet (group). Below, I have attempted to simplify the core issue by avoiding to define the function directly.

### Attempt

```
# Initial setup
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars
group = "cyl"
variable = "mpg"
gform <- reformulate(".", response=group)
data[[group]] <- as.factor(data[[group]])

# Make data for normal curves
dat_norm <- data %>% group_by(.data[[group]]) %>% 
  summarise(mpg=seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                  max(.[[variable]]), 
                  length.out=100),
            density=dnorm(seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                        max(.[[variable]]), 
                        length.out=100), 
                    mean(.[[variable]]), 
                    sd(.[[variable]])))

# Make plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes_string(x=variable, fill=group)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_line(data=dat_norm, aes_string(x=variable, y="density", group=group), size=1.2) +
  facet_grid(gform)
```

[image]

You can see that the problem here is that it seems like ggplot applies the same data to all facets and do not customize by group. We can do it manually **however the problem is that this approach does not allow for an unknown number of groups for the final function.**

### Desired outcome

```
# As explained above, the previous figure has the same line for each facet.
# I would like to have the following instead:    
norm.1 <- data %>%
  filter(.[[group]]==levels(.[[group]])[1]) %>%
  with(data.frame(x = seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                          max(.[[variable]]), 
                          length.out=100), 
                  y = dnorm(seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                                max(.[[variable]]), 
                                length.out=100), 
                            mean(.[[variable]]), 
                            sd(.[[variable]])))) %>%
  mutate_(cyl = factor(levels(data[[group]])[1],levels = levels(data[[group]])))


norm.2 <- data %>%
  filter(.[[group]]==levels(.[[group]])[2]) %>%
  with(data.frame(x = seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                          max(.[[variable]]), 
                          length.out=100), 
                  y = dnorm(seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                                max(.[[variable]]), 
                                length.out=100),
                            mean(.[[variable]]),
                            sd(.[[variable]])))) %>%
  mutate_(cyl = factor(levels(data[[group]])[2],levels = levels(data[[group]])))

norm.3 <- data %>%
  filter(.[[group]]==levels(.[[group]])[3]) %>%
  with(data.frame(x = seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                          max(.[[variable]]), 
                          length.out=100), 
                  y = dnorm(seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                                max(.[[variable]]), 
                                length.out=100), 
                            mean(.[[variable]]), 
                            sd(.[[variable]])))) %>%
  mutate_(cyl = factor(levels(data[[group]])[3],levels = levels(data[[group]])))


# Make plot
ggplot(data, aes_string(x=variable, fill=group)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_grid(gform) +
  geom_line(data = norm.1, aes(x = x, y = y), size=1.2) +
  geom_line(data = norm.2, aes(x = x, y = y), size=1.2) +
  geom_line(data = norm.3, aes(x = x, y = y), size=1.2)
```

[image]

### Question

As explained, the latter approach forces me to repeat the `geom_line()` calls as many times as there are groups. However, within the function, we will not know the number of groups in advance. What would be the solution?

Note: This is a follow-up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511244/custom-function-allow-unknown-number-of-groups-for-operations/66512019?noredirect=1#comment117595206_66512019).

Comment: ggplot is behaving correctly.  The data frame you are creating (dat_norm) is simply repeating the overall distribution 3 times.   You will have to apply or map or slice or something to get each of the cyl isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot is behaving correctly. The data frame you are creating (dat_norm) is simply repeating the overall distribution 3 times. One small change to your summarise will make it respect the grouping:

```r
# Initial setup
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars
group = "cyl"
variable = "mpg"
gform <- reformulate(".", response=group)
data[[group]] <- as.factor(data[[group]])

# Make data for normal curves
dat_norm <- data %>% group_by(.data[[group]]) %>% 
# HERE IS THE CHANGE: do( 
  do(summarise(.,mpg=seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                    max(.[[variable]]), 
                    length.out=100),
            density=dnorm(seq(min(.[[variable]]), 
                              max(.[[variable]]), 
                              length.out=100), 
                          mean(.[[variable]]), 
                          sd(.[[variable]]))))

# Make plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes_string(x=variable, fill=group)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_line(data=dat_norm, aes_string(x=variable, y="density", group=group), size=1.2) +
  facet_grid(gform)
```

Comment: I understand do is superceded, and you can likely get this same behavior in a number of more modern ways!

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Do you think you could expand in your answer on how you came to that answer and what `do` does? E.g., how does it change the dataframe and how does that make ggplot accept it correctly (and why)?

Comment: from: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/07/dplyr-do-some-tips-for-using-and-programming/ - "it is conceived to be used with dplyr group_by() to compute operations within groups" - basically it tells dplyr to do everything by group, rather than the whole data frame.  There are more modern ways to achieve the same goal, but I still like do because it works!